# How to place multiple plots at specific coordinates using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Many questions have been asked before about overlaying multiple plots in ggplot. However, my question is slightly different.

Basically, I am trying to plot a list of ggplot objects at specific coordinates on a graphic of a grid (that is created using ggplot). Hopefully my example below will explain more clearly.

To begin, create some data:

```
set.seed(100)
m <- matrix(runif(9, -1, 1), ncol = 3)
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- LETTERS[1:3]
m[lower.tri(m)] = t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
diag(m) <- 0
col1 <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(10,"BrBG"))
```

Then Im reshaping the data and creating the grid graphic to match the size of my data matrix:

```
df <- reshape2::melt(m)
df$abs <- abs(df$value)
df$Var1 <- factor(df$Var1, levels = colnames(m))


ggrid <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = 1, height = 1), fill = NA, color = "grey50") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$Var1)), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1,
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

The above code creates this:

[image: gird]

Then I am creating a list of plots (in this case multiple pie charts).

```
plot_list <- list()
for(i in 1:9){
 plot_list[[i]] <-  ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = Var1)) +
   geom_col(color = "black") +
   coord_polar(theta = "y") +
   theme_void() +
   theme(legend.position = 'none')
}
```

So, now the `plot_list` object contains 9 ggplot pie charts. What I'm trying to do is place the pie charts in the appropriate position on the grid. For example, `plot_list[[1]]` would be in position `A,A` on the grid... `plot_list[[2]]` -> `A,B`...continuing row-wise.

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this. Ideally, my final goal is to make this work generically (that is, for any size grid/number of pie charts)

EDIT: To clarify, I would like my output to look like this (which I made in photoshop):

[image: example_plot]

That is, I'm trying to place each pie chart in the appropriate place on top of the `ggrid` object.

Comment: I am curious about the use case of this - I feel this might be a suboptimal approach to whatever you want to achieve

Comment: Honestly, it's just for fun/hobby. I was trying to recreate (in ggplot) a plot I saw. The plot in question is `corrplot::corrplot(corr, method = 'pie')`. I was curious to see how it could be made in ggplot

Comment: I see. Maybe of interest (which might be clear to you, but maybe not to a curious reader in the future) that corrplot::corrplot is not using ggplot, but drawing the plot directly with grid. On a quick skim of the function, I believe it calculates the positions of the little plots with https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/blob/0497ad6717c2909fb1ed0c75ff6d269605107808/R/corrplot.R#L480 and draws them from https://github.com/taiyun/corrplot/blob/0497ad6717c2909fb1ed0c75ff6d269605107808/R/corrplot.R#L801 onwards.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that. I knew it wasn't using ggplot, hence my curiosity about how you could replicate it in ggplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to add your pie charts on top of your `ggrid` plot would be to use `annotation_custom`. To this end I first create a dataframe containing the numeric positions to place the pies and the plots as another column. Afterwards you could use e.g. `purrr::pmap` to loop over the rows of this df and add the pies using multiple `annotation_custom` layers:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

plot_list <- lapply(seq(9), function(i) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = Var1)) +
    geom_col(color = "black") +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
})

pie_grid <- expand.grid(
  as.numeric(factor(unique(df$Var1))),
  as.numeric(factor(unique(df$Var2)))
)
pie_grid$plot <- plot_list

ggrid +
  purrr::pmap(pie_grid, function(Var1, Var2, plot) {
    annotation_custom(
      grob = ggplotGrob(plot),
      xmin = Var1 - .5, xmax = Var1 + .5,
      ymin = Var2 - .5, ymax = Var2 + .5
    )
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ggmatrix](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/ggmatrix.html) from GGally.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
ggmatrix(plot_list, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, xlab = "Var1", ylab = "Var2", xAxisLabels = c("A", "B", "C"), yAxisLabels = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I could plot the grid of plots using `GGally` or `gridExtra`. But I'm trying to plot the grid object `ggrid` in my code, and then place each pie chart on top of `ggrid`. I think I should modify my question to be more clear.

Comment: Are you just wanting the grid lines or is there a reason that isn't apparent in the example?

Comment: well, I was trying to replicate the plot with the gridlines